# Check if user exists in LDAP with ApplicationDirectory context

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm using the following code to to check if user exists in LDAP

```
     using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, domainName, Ole5.Entity.Account.Account.Configuration.AD_Username, Ole5.Entity.Account.Account.Configuration.AD_Password))
            {
                using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
                {
                    return foundUser != null;
                }
            }
```

the error i get is

> a container and name must be specified when using the application directory context

what is the container and name means, and what should i fill them?

Comment: I'm using C# .Net v4.5

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you need to use a different constructor method for `PrincipalContext` to specify the container. [This is the one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextType_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_) you need to use. The only difference is the added `container` parameter.

```
public PrincipalContext (ContextType contextType, string name, string container, string userName, string password);
```